# Cannot install PyMySQL because of a [Errno 13] permission denied error

Tags: python, pymysql

I am trying to connect and download pymysql to create databases through python but when I do

```
pip install pymysql
```

into the terminal I get the following error message

```
 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymysql'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I am very new to python so any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo pip install pymysql      # Installs for all the users.
```

Or:

```
pip install pymysql --user    # Installs the package for the current user only.
```